# AT command in Android

Tags: android, at-command

I want to use AT command in my application to set some order to GSM modem.

I searched Google but i could not find any good answer!

Do you have  any solution?

and can i use ADB to send AT command to android?

Comment: I have feeling Android has no API for such. But maybe with native C extensions.

Comment: @00 00 Sorry but I can't really tell what you are trying to do. If you could give us some more information what AT commands are (maybe a relevant link) and what you want to do in general we would be able to help you.

Comment: yes...maybe NDK could help us.
but for that we need know some about it s port name and detail.

Comment: @Janusz : AT command are some commands that you can connect with GSM modem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_command

Comment: in general i want to say something to GSM modem.for example call a phone number(i do not want use android APIs like telephony and etc.).

Comment: I hope that this is not possible in Android because it would render the Android permission system useless.

Comment: @Janusz : it s a great for developers.android better give this permission to root users.

Comment: @Janusz: It wouldn't render anything useless. Only applications with sufficient permissions should be able to start raw communication with the modem.

Comment: @Jan That would also be a way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first you have to root the phone then in adb shell

```
su

echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0
```

if you want to see answer use

```
cat /dev/smd0
```

i've test this command in samsung mini,cooper,s+ and it works.

if you use htc (htc rhyme tested) try to adb shell and type this command "radiooptions 13 AT" if you want to see answer type "logcat -b radio"

try echo to /dev/smd0 for other devices

*you can use this command in sdk java code by using Runtime.exec (require su)

example : echo -e "ATD123456789;\r" > /dev/smd0  ----> (call to number 123456789)

Comment: In my case (Allwinner a31) the device is `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: Does anybody know what's the node for nexus 4? Also will you have to stop the ril daemon before sending the command?