# How to use AT commands and implement CSD in Android?

Tags: android, at-command

I've got a challenge: I need to implement CSD into my Android app.

Android Telephony organization is explained here
http://ytd2525.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/android-operating-system-and-radio-interface-layer/.

Since Android API doesn't include methods to work with hardware modem directly (send AT command and get back reply), I suppose I have to work with port which represents modem.

In this post [AT command in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022525/at-command-in-android?rq=1) port ***/dev/smd0*** is recommended to use, but my Samsung Galaxy S III does not have such port.

Question: Does anybody knows how to interact with modem (what is hardware port name, how to send AT command, how to get back modem's reply)? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way that will work across all Android phones.  You may find a method that works with 1 or 2 models, but that's about it.

Comment: OK, but I have no clue about how to find a method that works with 1 model at least, do you?