# How to useAT commands in Android by 'root' the phone

Tags: android, android-ndk, linux-kernel, google-play, at-command

We have various Android devices of Spike, Samsung, Micromax. How to give AT commands from Android device to modem?

We searched in Google Play but did not find any app related to this. Can you please suggest way by which we can use AT commands with Android phone.

[AT command in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022525/at-command-in-android), this question suggesting `first you have to root the phone...`, how to do this?

@EDIT: I need for Android Spice Mi-270 mobile

Thanks.

Comment: Do some [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+root+android) first, if you still can't figure it out http://android.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for your question.

Comment: @dst +1. Many thanks, I was not knowing about specific Android site of stackexchange.

Comment: As described in the android tag's description, the android site shall be used for non-developer questions, while app development and similar stuff is discussed here.