# Access Modem - Android Device (Nexus 5)

Tags: android, windows, at-command, modem, nexus-5

> **Device** : Google Nexus 5 (Un-rooted)
>   **Host Machine** : Window 7

I want to Access Android Device as a Modem (using **COM** or **Modem Port**) and eventually pass AT Commands using HyperTerminal/Teraterm.

So after connecting the device to a Windows Box, The Device gets **detected** under Device Manager, but doesn't show any COM Port (other than the default COM0).

On right click and update driver, It shows it cannot find drivers.

I have tried the following options, but no luck with any.

1. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022525/at-command-in-android) on a *rooted* Nexus 5, but doesn't expose which */dev/smdX* to use. Tried all combinations, didn't work.
2. Tried the [Google USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) from the Google Android's Website. No changes.
3. From [here](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-5-driver-adb-fastboot-installation-guide). I Installed drivers from LG Electronics, No changes in COM Port.
4. Universal Naked Driver helped me get to ADB Shell interface, but
   thats not what I want.

In all of the Above procedure USB Debugging was enabled (Just saying).

I also heard the phone has to put into **Modem mode** to fire AT Commands.
If so, How do I do that ?
Or Is this a device **driver Issue** ?

> **Conclusion:**
>   I want to access the Modem of the Android Device and fire AT Commands to it.

Could you please tell what am I missing ?
Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give an exact answer to this question, because it depends on how the manufacturer has implemented the device drivers.  Unfortunately, there is a lot of information that isn't in the public domain.

It is possible, that the manufacturer has implemented some code to convert the device to a modem.  Doing this yourself is device-specific, and proprietary.  You might be able to get hold of a converter, for example bundled with the manufacturer's dashboard application for the PC, if such a thing exists.

Some devices don't expose the modem port at all.  They may be visible as a network adapter, or as an always-connected LAN connection.  If the device is visible as a network adapter, then you can access it via Windows Mobile Broadband API, or via MBIM for some newer devices.

To check if the device is visible as a network adapter, and get information about it, open a cmd box and type

```
netsh mbn show interfaces
```

Windows Mobile Broadband API doesn't give as many details as a good AT command set, but performs basically the same functions.  MBIM is an industry standard interface with similar functionality, available on the Windows 8+ desktop via the Mobile Broadband DeviceServices API, for devices that support it.

If the device shows as an always-on LAN connection, there is probably a proprietary, high level interface for mobile functionality.

Driver behaviour can differ for different operating systems.  If you have the chance to try the device on Windows Vista, 7 and 8, you may see different behaviour.